# SAPUI5:: Difference between core:view and mvc:view

Tags: sapui5

Can someone explain in brief or re-direct me to appropriate link to understand the difference between `core:view` and `mvc:view` in XML view of SAPUI5/Fiori application?

When we start an application in Eclipse and create XML view using sap.m library we see `core:view`, but in sample applications in SAPUI5 SDK - Demo Kit, we are seeing `mvc:view`. Please help us understanding when to use what.

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
  controllerName="splitapptest.Master" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <Page title="Title">
  <content>

  </content>
  </Page>
</core:View>
```

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/541

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `View` control is in `sap.ui.core.mvc`: see [`Class sap.ui.core.mvc.View`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.View.html) in the API documentation. Therefore, the namespace for a `View` element in an XML view definition is `sap.ui.core.mvc`.

This usually translates to something like:

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"…>
```

but of course the prefix is arbitrary and you could just as well have:

```xml
<banana:View xmlns:banana="sap.ui.core.mvc"…>
```

The point is that it's the namespace that's important, at least technically. The confusion probably arises because the XML processor is rather lenient on the namespace specified for the root `View` element.

So to answer your question specifically, while `core:View` might be "correct" if you crazily specified `xmlns:core="sap.ui.core.mvc"`, it would be very confusing, so the best way to express it is

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"…>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```xml
<a xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
   controllerName="splitapptest.Master" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <Page title="Title">
        <content>
    </content>
   </Page>
 </a>
```

it will also work. The declaration does not matter. `XMLTemplateProcessor` will not parse this element.